# How to correctly initiate DOM element height for height-transition?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, tailwind-css, css-transitions

I'm using a `height-transition`, which can't transition from or to `height: auto` CSS setting so I have to use `javascript` inside my `vue` components to extract the DOM element's `scrollHeight` and use it as transition target height.

This DOM element has the height transition:

```
<div
  class="transition-all duration-300 overflow-hidden"
  :style="{ height: open ? state.height : '0' }"
  ref="tab">
  ...
```

The only thing that worked so far is a `setTimeout` function despite being a not so clean approach:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  // workaround to initiate correct tab height for transition to work
  state.height = `${tab.value.scrollHeight}px`
}, 1000)
```

this works because the correct height gets initiated during component mount and render, so the user doesn't notice that the tab only gets rendered correctly after 1000ms.

Still, I'd like to know if there is a more robust approach than this. I've tried:

```
onMounted(async () => {
  await nextTick()
  state.height = `${tab.value.scrollHeight}px`
})
```

or

```
watch(
  () => tab.value.scrollHeight,
  async () => {
    await nextTick()
    state.height = `${tab.value.scrollHeight}px`
  }
)
```

or

```
watch(
  () => tab.value,
  async () => {
    await nextTick()
    state.height = `${tab.value.scrollHeight}px`
  },
  { deep: true }
)
```

none of which sets the correct initial value to `state.height`. Only a timeout seems to help.

Comment: May be you need to add a important to your classes.